# Adding new record in DataView on condition different values in columns in record?

Tags: c#, loops, dataview, datarowview

I have a DataView in my code-behind page : `DataView _dvListing = _dt.DefaultView;`
What I want to do is loop through the view/table and check the column value of the current record with the value in the same column in the previous record. If it is different I want to add a new record after the current record. An example will be:

Current Rec col X = "Team B", Previous Rec col X = "Team A", therefore INSERT New Rec with Col X = "Team B"

Would I need to use datarow view in a FOR loop?

Thx in advance

Mo

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use select statement instead.